# Google Sheets Query - Not like partial match

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, google-query-language

So I have this formula, and it's working as intended but I would like to further refine the data.

Formula:

```
=QUERY('Users'!A1:Q, "Select A,B,C,F,G,O,Q where Q >= 180 and Q < 44223")
```

I have tried:

```
=QUERY('Users'!A1:Q, "Select A,B,C,F,G,O,Q where Q >= 180 and Q < 44223 and F not like '*text*'")
```

But that caused an error. Ideally, I would like to ommet any results that match partial texts in columns C and F. Any ideas?

EDIT:
Included a link to an [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SYQSS5xBZ1R0ZItDVLrt1gImAZqFQPrjrwBkDUhbSA4/edit?usp=sharing)

Ideally, I want the query to match everything in column F except 'Archived' (but needs to be wildcarded) and everything in column C except Delta (again, needs to be wildcarded)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!A1:Q6, 
 "select A,B,C,F,G,O,Q 
  where Q >= 180 
    and Q < 44223 
    and not lower(O) matches '.*archived.*' 
    and not lower(C) matches '.*delta.*'")
```

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, that doesn't filter out the results that match the keyword. If my keyword is 'magic', for example and the column contains 'black magic' and 'white magic' and axe - I would only want to return those that match axe. This is an example, so just matching axe wouldn't do

Comment: @SL8t7 can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I have added a link to the example sheet

Comment: Also have tried to better explain what I am trying to get done